# Angular: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) routing issue

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I want to remove the `#` from my URLs, so I have the code below:

```
angular.module('building')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 
        function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

            // Turn on #-less links.
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $stateProvider
                .state('building', {
                    url:'/building',
                    templateUrl: 'app/modules/building/building.html',
                    controller: 'BuildingQuery',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

    }]);
```

And I have `<base href="/">` in my `index.html` file.

And the code works...sort of.

If I enter a link like this...

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/#/building
```

Then the browser redirects that URL to...

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/building
```

and loads the page.

However, if I enter this url...

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/building
```

then...

```
Cannot GET /building
```

Because the `#` URLs redirect properly, I know `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` is doing *something*.

Any ideas? It might be useful to know that I'm using [angm](https://github.com/newaeonweb/generator-angm) to generate the modules.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> **Using [html5mode] requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
>   have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
>   (e.g. index.html)**. Requiring a <base> tag is also important for this
>   case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the
>   url that is the application base and the path that should be handled
>   by the application.

I.e. you need to tell your server to rewrite any requests to /building to /index.html.

Answer (score 0):

evsheino pointed me in the right direction. There's nothing wrong with my code, it was the server configuration causing problems. All I had to do was add the following to my gruntfile.js

```
middleware: function (connect, options) {
    var optBase = (typeof options.base === 'string') ? [options.base] : options.base;
                    return [require('connect-modrewrite')(['!(\\..+)$ / [L]'])].concat(
                        optBase.map(function(path){ return connect.static(path); }));
                },
                keepalive: true,
                port: 4000,
                base: '.',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                debug: true,
                livereload: true,
                open: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Full explanation can be found here: http://jjt.io/2013/11/16/angular-html5mode-using-yeoman-generator-angular/

EDIT: this was for [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)